# Spark submit local Executor cannot fetch jar

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was trying to run a Spark example from their docs:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/quick-start.html

Whenever I try section Self-Contained Applications I get the following output:

```
16/08/28 13:18:30 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.5.1
16/08/28 13:18:30 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: alejandrohernandez
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: alejandrohernandez
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(alejandrohernandez); users with modify permissions: Set(alejandrohernandez)
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.15.3:56988]
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 56988.
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/lb/78w91_l123n0cvprhmldkxhc0000gp/T/blockmgr-be8bedf7-96fe-425b-8344-c668110905eb
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 530.0 MB
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /private/var/folders/lb/78w91_l123n0cvprhmldkxhc0000gp/T/spark-a122037d-3228-4e53-b3dd-6d7213187df0/httpd-e3388b36-1605-4cc5-a4c1-def1b7660570
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 56989.
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.15.3:4040
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/Users/alejandrohernandez/repos/AssetBreakdownUploader/target/scala-2.10/AssetBreakdownUploader-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar at http://192.168.15.3:56989/jars/AssetBreakdownUploader-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar with timestamp 1472408311863
16/08/28 13:18:31 WARN MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 56990.
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 56990
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:56990 with 530.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 56990)
16/08/28 13:18:31 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/08/28 13:18:32 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(108600) called with curMem=0, maxMem=555755765
16/08/28 13:18:32 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 106.1 KB, free 529.9 MB)
16/08/28 13:18:32 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(11386) called with curMem=108600, maxMem=555755765
16/08/28 13:18:32 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 11.1 KB, free 529.9 MB)
16/08/28 13:18:32 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:56990 (size: 11.1 KB, free: 530.0 MB)
16/08/28 13:18:32 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at Main.scala:12
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: count at Main.scala:13
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (count at Main.scala:13) with 1 output partitions
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0(count at Main.scala:13)
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at filter at Main.scala:13), which has no missing parents
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(3224) called with curMem=119986, maxMem=555755765
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.1 KB, free 529.9 MB)
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1925) called with curMem=123210, maxMem=555755765
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1925.0 B, free 529.9 MB)
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on localhost:56990 (size: 1925.0 B, free: 530.0 MB)
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:861
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at filter at Main.scala:13)
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2258 bytes)
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
16/08/28 13:18:33 INFO Executor: Fetching http://192.168.15.3:56989/jars/AssetBreakdownUploader-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar with timestamp 1472408311863
16/08/28 13:19:33 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:555)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:397)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/08/28 13:19:33 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:555)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:397)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/08/28 13:19:33 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
16/08/28 13:19:33 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/08/28 13:19:33 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
16/08/28 13:19:33 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (count at Main.scala:13) failed in 60.069 s
16/08/28 13:19:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: count at Main.scala:13, took 60.144276 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:555)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:397)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1496)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1822)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1835)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1848)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1919)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1121)
    at com.ooyala.uploader.Main$.main(Main.scala:13)
    at com.ooyala.uploader.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:555)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:397)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/08/28 13:19:33 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/08/28 13:19:33 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.15.3:4040
16/08/28 13:19:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
16/08/28 13:19:33 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/08/28 13:19:33 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/08/28 13:19:33 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/08/28 13:19:33 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/08/28 13:19:33 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/08/28 13:19:33 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/08/28 13:19:33 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/08/28 13:19:33 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/lb/78w91_l123n0cvprhmldkxhc0000gp/T/spark-a122037d-3228-4e53-b3dd-6d7213187df0
```

When executing, I wait for some time at this point

```
16/08/28 13:22:21 INFO Executor: Fetching http://192.168.15.3:57015/jars/AssetBreakdownUploader-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar with timestamp 1472408540577
```

until the timeout happens. Any ideas of what can be happening?

Comment: Looks like there's a communication problem between your driver and executors. Are all relevant ports open?

Comment: For the record, everything works fine when running the examples with spark-shell

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I think that's the main problem, as far as I understand the ports for the http file server are randomly chosen whenever spark submit is launched. The jar is successfully uploaded to the http file server, I ls'd before the job finished and the jar was there, it's only the executor that cannot fetch it.

Comment: Can you telnet from the executor to the driver?

Comment: A bit late, but same issue here on hdp2.6: 
So any more info on this?
i think it's a proxy problem (at least for me), but spark should use the DNS name whose domain name is excluded in the proxy settings.
But for some reason spark uses the ip. Why?